# Click on email imageview

Tags: android, email, button, textview, onclicklistener

All i want is when i click on email on textbox it open email or gmail whatever, and when it open email or another app it write the email in the adress, and i know that i need to put the textview clickable just help me with code if it is possible and simple.

**Java Class :**

```
  ImageView ivImageFromUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        ivImageFromUrl = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image_from_url);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i67.tinypic.com/20k9n42.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
        OnClickButtonListener();


        TextView numTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        numTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel: 244892501"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        })

        ;
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener() {

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Contactos.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: on click textview it open the app email and write the email that is on textview simple as dat.

Comment: oh i forgot to put the xml file but i have a image view

Comment: To clarify, you want to click the ImageView, then open email app containing the text of a different TextView you have? Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a click listener on your ImageView. Use `getText().toString()` on your `TextView to get the text, then add it to your email intent  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);`. See below. You'll need to set your TextView as final so it can be accessed in the onClick

```
final TextView textView = findViewById(...)

imageView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = textView.getText().toString();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", emailAddress, null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject"); // Whatever subject
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email"));
    }
});
```